# Revalue a plot axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting a Matrix with contourf, the Matrix is 883x883, the problem is that when plotting it the axis in the plots go from 0 to 883, but I would like to give it another values, more exactly, I'd like it to go from -20 to 20. How can I set that? I am very new in python, so I'd appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your post to add your code. Depending on what your code looks like you can set your axes limits e.g. `plt.xlim(xmin,xmax)`

Comment: The Code is only this: im2=ax2.contourf(  MC, 50)
   where MC is the matrix

Comment: But I already tried with plt.xlim(xmin,xmax) and what I got is that the only part of the Matrix represente was the part that starts in -20 and goes to 20, and since there is Nothing from -20 to 0, that was a blank space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [contourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html), you can provide the location of your data points using the optional X and Y arguments. This will only work as expected if your data is structured, meaning if you can generate a grid made of rectangles for which the nodes would represent the location of your data points. If this is not the case, then I would suggest using a [triangulation](https://matplotlib.org/api/tri_api.html) and provide it to [tricontourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html).

Comment: Thank you, I'm new in python and I didn't know that property of countourf, and it just worked perfectly :)